# Tuple index out of range Tkinter

Tags: graph, indexing, plot, tkinter, tuples

So I've got a program that should take a function as input and graph it on a Tkinter canvas.

```
    def draw(self):
    self.canvas.delete(ALL)
    for n, i in enumerate(self.sav):
        self.function, colour = self.sav_func[n]
        i = self.p1(i)
        i = self.p2(i, self.function, colour)
        if i != [0]:
            try:
                self.canvas.create_line(i, fill = colour)
            except TclError as err:
                tkMessageBox.showerror(TclError, err)
                self.sav.remove(self.sav[len(self.sav)-1])
                self.sav_func.remove(self.sav_func[len(self.sav_func)-1])
```

This section is giving me the following error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Google Drive/assign2_2-1.py", line 113, in add_func
    self.redraw_all()
  File "D:/Google Drive/assign2_2-1.py", line 132, in redraw_all
    self.draw()
  File "D:/Google Drive/assign2_2-1.py", line 145, in draw
    self.canvas.create_line(i, fill = colour)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2201, in create_line
    return self._create('line', args, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2182, in _create
    cnf = args[-1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

From what I can gather it's something to do with the number of inputs not matching the number of outputs, but I'm still a little lost. Help would be great!

Comment: your indentation is incorrect in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like `i` doesn't have enough values. To create a line it needs four values: x1,y1,x2,y2.